# What is the best way to deal with legacy code not in version control?

Tags: project-management, version-control, legacy

What is the best way to develop and maintain legacy code not in version control? Adding it to version control is of course the obvious answer, but if you can't, for some reason, what would you do?

A few reasons I can think of why version control wouldn't be possible are:

- Management is against it (doesn't understand it, thinks it would take to much time, isn't worth it, etc.)
- You don't have the administritative privileges to install the required software.
- The code runs/is stored on legacy systems with limited capabilities for version control.

So, if real version control isn't available, what do you do? Set up some regular backup system? Or perhaps create version-named folders?

Comment: Do you have a directory where you can write? If you don't, you can't compile either, so there must be somewhere. Put the VCS into a directory where you can install it. Put the code under the management of your VCS. Make a branch for whatever is 'out there' in the untamed wilderness; make another branch for you to work on; use a third branch to release too (this might be the trunk or master or main branch).  Work with the VCS on your copy of the code. Be careful to deal with other people's changes to the code too. But don't change a thing until you've got the original under version control!

Comment: If you can't do it because of either of your first two bullet points, the best way to deal with the problem is to find a new job. If there's a hand grenade on your desk with the pin pulled out, don't ask on StackExchange how to defuse it - just get the hell out.

Comment: @Jonathan - I don't think the problem is compiling the legacy code after moving it to version control, it's installing an application like git or svn to use for version control.  The dev environment here is for an intranet, so the VCS can't be compiled (unless you know of a complete one written in Javascript...)

Comment: @Kevin: You can usually find precompiled packages.  If you can't get hold of those, either, then @Carson63000 has the right idea; it is time to run.  I decline to work without a VCS - or several - available to me.  I rely on them to keep things straight for me, and allow me to revert to a previous version at any time that I need to do so.  Heck, even VSS is better than nothing (though that's a close call).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is **no** reason to not be able to have version control *period*.

If management is against it even after having the benefits pointed out to them, they're clearly not fit to be managers and their boss should be approached.

If you don't have administrative privileges, either get them or have someone from IT install the software.

The code shouldn't be executed *and* be stored on the same machine. You should have centralized source control with a proper deployment pipeline.

Comment: I agree. But, there exists legacy code so large (say, 30000+ lines of code) that cannot easily be run or tested on any other machines than those (old ones) it resides on, so development needs to take place there. (Code still in use but which is so convoluted and interdependent that any radical changes would take longer than rewriting it all.) What would you do then? Version control somewhere else, and transfer the code between somehow?

Comment: Oh, perhaps "management against it" wasn't a reason after all. But I believe "runs on legacy systems" might have some merit.

Comment: There's always a solution to the "runs on legacy systems" argument. If there's a network connection, then it should be trivial to host a source control server on another machine and deploy to the host machine, even if the host itself can't run a source control client for whatever reason (have you tried compiling a source control client for the target platform by any chance?)

Comment: there is no need for the source control to be centralized, the rest of it sounds right

Comment: @jk: The OP eluded to the source running/existing on multiple machines, in which case the source control *should* be centralized.

Comment: No reason not to use source control.  You can run subversion on a low end desktop machine these days.  For the most part the software will be free, the "server" will run about 300-500 dollars if you don't have a spare, and then the cost of backing it up regularly.  As far as getting it on to the machine it needs to run on:  In a worst case scenario compile it on a dev machine and transfer it to the host machine using physical media to test.  This is assuming you have no network connectivity.

Comment: @tgwizard: 30,000 LOC is *nothing*. Hell, a Debian Linux release is estimated at 325 *million* LOC. As Demian said, there is *no excuse* for not having this stuff under version control.

Comment: @PeterRowell True, but Debian has been in active development for several years, by great programmers, so that code is quite a bit cleaner :)

Comment: @DemianBrecht, @Aliester: The system I'm thinking of is a large intranet web site, so development on a separate machine is somewhat problematic, with all the setup required for webserver/databases/nightly data transfer scripts etc.

Comment: @tgwizard: Cleanliness as nothing to do with this. Even if the whole thing is one giant, twisted mass of snakes it needs to be tracked. In fact it may be even *more* important for nasty code to be tracked because any single change could cause the whole thing to explode in your face.

Comment: @tgwizard: The result of the setup *far* outweighs the cost. There's **no** way that development should be done on the live server for any web-based system (if that's the case). Proper dev environments should be set up with proper version control and deployment pipelines.

Comment: I agree with both of you. And yes, development on the live server is not acceptable. But unfortunately, that is how the system works, and, again unfortunately, there's not much I can do about that (because of the interconnectedness and databases and nightly scripts, as I mentioned before).

Comment: But I could probably swing Git or Mercurial on a desktop pc, which might work.

Comment: @tgwizard: There's *always* something that can be changed to get your dev environment up and running. I'm not saying that it will be a small or easy task. It may take several weeks or a month or two of analysis and design prior to implementing the changes. However, they are *very* much worthwhile and something that I would urge you to look into further.

Comment: @Demian I will, and I'll start with just simple VC and go from there. Thanks for the answers and the discussion!

Comment: Wait, 30 THOUSAND lines of code is "so large that [it] cannot easily be run or tested on any other machines"? Are these lines millions of characters long?

Comment: It is not the amount of code that makes it impractical to setup a dev machine, but the interdependence of it all. (I don't know exactly how large the codebase is, 30K was a guess.) It would be easier to rewrite it all (which is frowned upon...)

Answer (score 3):

Git is written in fairly portable C and does not require administrative privileges.  That's just one of your options.  Nothing unusual about version control being on a separate system from the runtime, either.  I write embedded software with the version control server, development environment, and runtime environment all on separate machines.

Answer (score 1):

Check the IT backup plan for whereever the code is stored.  That covers you in case of issues, but it can also give you some valuable back-catalog versions of the project if there are old tapes.

If they are not against keeping multiple versions of the codebase separated by folder, might as well start there.  Folders with dates or version numbers is better than nothing.

Though if they let you create those, it is not a very far step to start up a version control, even if it is just a userspace one.  Git is in C, so you can likely get it running, even if you are under tight restrictions.  (After all, their source compiles somewhere, right?)

Just add a network connection and you've got a real VCS, which has become a basic necessity for programming.

Comment: It's a intranet, so no compilation needed. This makes coding and testing on a separate machine a bit problematic, though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need admin permissions for all version control systems. Git and Mercurial are two that are free, lightweight and don't require a centralized server.

I can't see any objection they would have to you running it locally and checking the files in there. If you really need to have a centralized server you could do an online service like Github, BitBucket, or Kiln; none of which require a local install requiring admin rights on a server.

Comment: This is be a bad advice. I can imagine the outrage from management (imho totally understandable), when you put *company property* out on a *server on the internet*...